# NSMutableString appendString vs appendFormat, which is more efficient?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Given this:

```
NSString *innerXml = @"somevalue";
NSMutableString *xml = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Which of these is faster; **not** asking about readability, which is subjective:

1.

```
[xml appendFormat:@"<randomElement>%@</randomElement>", innerXml];
```

2.

```
[xml appendString:@"<randomElement>"];
[xml appendString:innerXml];
[xml appendString:@"</randomElement>"];
```

Comment: And profile it on strings of the size that you are expecting. If it's important, you'll probably want a Swift version as well.

Comment: If you really care time it. But in general premature optimization is not worth the effort, it is much better to write good code and then profile the app and if there is a performance issue work on the pinpointed performance areas. Generally with premature optimization the wrong things are targeted.

Comment: @zaph that's why I made sure to put the comment about readability; yes I'm quite aware of premature optimization. Was just curious of how it's implemented internally since I'm not as familiar with Objective-C/LLDB as much as I am with .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really curious about the implementation read the source code, it is available online, see: [CFString.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-368.27/String.subproj/CFString.c).

Essentially the core foundation code is available as part of the opensourceing of the darwin kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the link - fascinating!